# Problema con FileStream en C# (Acceso denegado a la ruta de acceso)

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2013

```
Buen día tengan ustedes.
```

Tengo el siguiente problema, utilizo Visual Studio 2013, he creado un sistema donde se hace las operaciones básicas (buscar, eliminar, ingresar), enlazado a una base de datos creada en SQL SERVER 2008.
El problema me resulta cuando intentó ingresar un nuevo registro con foto, me dice lo siguiente:

```
Acceso denegado a la ruta de acceso 'C:\Users\Mi-Pc\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\EDICION CON BUNIFU\SISTEMA\SISTEMA \bin'.
```

El código que utilizo donde me sale la parte del error es el siguiente:

```
private void buniVista_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtnumero.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Digite Numero del modelo para Continuar","SISTEMA", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            txtnumero.Focus();
        }
        else if (txtdescripcion.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Digite la descripcion para Continuar", " SISTEMA", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            txtdescripcion.Focus();
        }
        else if (dtpfecha.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Digite fecha para Continuar", " SISTEMA ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            dtpfecha.Focus();
        }
        else if (txtTalla.Text == "SELECCIONE TALLA")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Seleccione talla para Continuar", " SISTEMA ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            txtTalla.Focus();

        }
        else if (txtexaminar.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cargue una fotografia para Continuar", " SISTEMA ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            btnexaminar.Focus();

        }
        else
        {
            FileStream stream = new FileStream(txtexaminar.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            //Se inicailiza un flujo de archivo con la imagen seleccionada desde el disco.
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(stream);
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(txtexaminar.Text);

            //Se inicializa un arreglo de Bytes del tamaño de la imagen
            byte[] binData = new byte[stream.Length];
            //Se almacena en el arreglo de bytes la informacion que se obtiene del flujo de archivos(foto)
            //Lee el bloque de bytes del flujo y escribe los datos en un búfer dado.
            stream.Read(binData, 0, Convert.ToInt32(stream.Length));

            ////Se muetra la imagen obtenida desde el flujo de datos
            picfotografia.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);

            VistaModelo f2 = new VistaModelo();
            this.Hide();
            f2.Show();

            f2.lblnumero.Text = txtnumero.Text.ToString();
            f2.lbldescripcion.Text = txtdescripcion.Text.ToString();
            f2.lblfecha.Text = dtpfecha.Text.ToString();
            f2.lbltalla.Text = txtTalla.Text.ToString();
            f2.txtexaminar2.Text = txtexaminar.Text.ToString();
            f2.picfoto.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
        }
    }
```

El error es específicamente en esta parte:

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream(txtexaminar.Text, FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);
```

Comment: ¿Es lenguaje C# o lenguaje C?

Comment: Hola @RyuzakiLpz, me surgió una pregunta, ¿por qué has decidido regresado la pregunta a una edición anterior?

Answer (score 3):

Ese error te lo envía debido a que deseas realizar el `FileStream` a una carpeta, lo cual debería ser a un archivo. Intenta agregando el nombre del archivo, a modo lo de ejemplo lo pondré de manera estática:

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream(txtexaminar.Text + "NombreArchivo.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

Comment: Op esta tratando de leer, no de guardar.

Comment: @gbianchi tienes razón, ya edité mi respuesta :)

Answer (score 1):

leyendo tu código creo que el problema básicamente se encuentra aquí

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream(txtexaminar.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

Debes asegurarte que el contenido de `txtexaminar.Text` sea una ruta válida a un archivo en cuya carpeta contenedora tengas permisos suficientes. Si no se indica en `txtexaminar.Text` una ruta, por defecto se usa la carpeta donde se encuentra 
 el ensamblado que ejecuta el código, en este caso

> C:\Users\Mi-Pc\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\EDICION CON
>   BUNIFU\SISTEMA\SISTEMA \bin

Así que te recomiendo hagas lo siguiente

```
string imagePathFolder = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImagePathFolder"]; // recuperar de configuración la carpeta de las imágenes
FileStream stream = new FileStream(System.IO.Path.Combine(imagePathFolder, txtexaminar.Text), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read); // acceder al archivo de la carpeta de las imágenes
```